# Need to dynamically-generate a "sticky note" text

Tags: jquery, css, flash

Working on a website that has an image of a sticky note which will change text somewhat frequently (every month or so) as new "todo" items are created on it.

Font I'm currently using is not Web Safe and the text is slightly angled to match the skew of the sticky note as well.

Now I'm a pragmatist, and in situations like this I would normally cede defeat and opt for something more CSS/HTML practical.  But no more!

I'm falling a bit behind on what's going on with HTML5, CSS3, PNG graphics, Flash (ugh), and/or any other rich visuals.  I'm decent with PHP/CSS/JS (jquery), have dabbled in Flash/actionscript too.

My question is: what tools/method should I be looking at here?

EDIT: I've switched to Comic Sans MS/Cursive -- pragmatism is fighting back furiously.

Comment: You can "cede" defeat, or "secede" from the Union. ;)

Comment: Nice catch! always get that one mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:  [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) and this Cufon [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/the-easiest-way-to-use-any-font-you-wish/).

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery Sticky note plugin](http://www.jquery-sticky-notes.com/)

Comment: +1 Very cool, but not quite what I'm after (I don't want users to be able to add/move the sticky).

Comment: I am sure you can just edit the plugin and take out that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll only be changing content once a month, and because the text is at an angle, Id probably go with a Flash solution, with a little css absolute positioning.  The whole angled text thing is really what throws a wrench into any practical solution.

Comment: If you think your site might ever be shown on an iPhone or iPad, I would strongly consider NOT using Flash...

Answer (score 0):

For the skewed/angled text, I'm going to use this method.  Thanks to all for the great tips.
http://someguynameddylan.com/lab/transform-origin-in-internet-explorer.php